# powershell can not read 2 dimension array content

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell

good morning, i am using powershell version 3.6 and want to read data from an MS Excel sheet. i wrote the following code:

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objworkbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($path)
$sheet = $objworkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$sheet.Visible = $true  

$r = $sheet.Range("A7:C12").value2 #$r is an 2d array
write-host $r[0][0]

$objworkbook.SaveAs($path)
$objworkbook.Close($false)
$objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = $False 
$objExcel.quit()
$ExcelProcess=get-process excel
$ExcelProcess | foreach {stop-process ($_.id)}
```

when i run this script it show me the contain of the range. but if i try get some value of the array with the index it don't work. and give this error back:

**The index [0] is not valid for access to a 2-dimensional array.
+             $r[0][0]
+             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NeedMultidimensionalIndex**

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: `$r[0[0]` = typo? you are missing a `]`. Try `$r[0,0]`...

Comment: sorry. i change it. thanks it works with `$r[0,0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
$r[0,0]
```

In my test have to start from 1 to have first value:

```
$r[1,1]
```

Comment: `$r[0][0]` can only be used with jagged arrays (i.e. arrays in arrays). Because OP has a 2-dimensional array, he needs to use a different notation: `$r[0,0]`. When `$r` is 1-dimensional, you get 2 items back, when `$r` is 2-dimensional, you get 1 item back.

Comment: thank you all very much. It works very well. with **$r[1,1]**