# How to slice a two-dimensional array in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a two-dimensional array from a database query by using an ADODB connection. Briefly, after opening the connection I retrieve a recordset by:

```
$rs2 = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Recordset

$sql = "<some SELECT statement here>"

$rs2.Open($sql, $conn)

$rows = $rs2.GetRows(1000)
```

I want to see just the first 10 rows for a particular column. So, I've tried:

```
$rows[0,(0..9)]
```

but it successfully fails giving the error:

```
You cannot index into a 2 dimensional array with index [0].
At line:1 char:1
+ $rows[0,(0..9)]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NeedMultidimensionalIndex
```

The array has 1000 rows and over 200 columns. I can use the syntax:

```
$rows[0,100]
```

without problems.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share the code that returns the database query to a PowerShell object, please? Or even just `$rows | Get-Type`? Traditionally I use a `System.Data.DataTable` object.

Comment: What does `$rows[0][0..9]` return? Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi, @gvee I've edited the post to reflect how I get the recordset.

Comment: Hi @VivekKumar, that syntax gave the same error.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981892/powershell-can-not-read-2-dimension-array-content) link. Looks similar.

Comment: Thanks @ViveKumar, but that doesn't solve the problem. The `$rows` is not a jagged array. The problem here is to know what is the correct syntax to slice a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index operator accepts a list of values, but if your array has a dimension > 1 that list must be a list of arrays, so that each individual list element identifies one element of your original array.

```
$indexes = 0..9 | ForEach-Object { ,@(0, $_) }
$rows[$indexes]
```

The leading comma in `,@(0, $_)` prevents PowerShell from unrolling the array `@(0, $_)` by wrapping it in another array that is unrolled instead.

Essentially you need to construct a list of tuples identifying the array elements you want to access, then use that list with the index operator.

`$rows[0][0..9]` doesn't work because you have a 2-dimensional array, not a jagged array (an array of arrays).

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers for the clear explanation. I knew this was going to be more counter-intuitive than expected :).

Comment: Actually I think it's rather straightforward considering how the index operator works.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using an ADODB.Recordset object, you have specific methods to access the data.

To get the value from the first row, first column:

```
$rows.GetValue(0,0)
```

first row, second column:

```
$rows.GetValue(1,0)
```

second row, sixth column:

```
$rows.GetValue(5,1)
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an answer. I can get individual values but the problem is with the array slicing.